# AppleScript variables passed to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, applescript, textedit

I am storing text from TextEdit in an AppleScript variable, and I want to pass it to JavaScript. I thought I was doing it right, but I still can't get the value to be stored. The code is as follows:

```
tell application "TextEdit"
    activate
    set docText to the text of the front document --This works. I've checked.
end tell

tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell window 1
        tell active tab
            execute javascript "function encryptDocument() {
                plainText = '" & docText & "';
                return plainText;
                } encryptDocument();"
                set skurp to the result
                display dialog skurp
            end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

The reason I house the JavaScript code within a `tell application "Google Chrome"` command is because I get an error every time I try to call it in the previous `tell application "TextEdit"` command. The error always says that it expects an end of line but found `"`. Not really sure why, but I can't find a way around this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that the value you want to give to the variable (I mean the text in Text Editor) contains a single quote (')?
Without ' in Text Editor this seems to work for me.

The following code snippet may be used to escape single quotes. (adapted from [this code](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/sbrt-06.html))

```
on escape(this_text)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the "'"
    set the item_list to every text item of this_text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the "\\'"
    set this_text to the item_list as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return this_text
end escape

tell application "TextEdit"
    activate
    set docText to the text of the front document --This works. I've checked.
end tell

set docText to escape(docText)

tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell window 1
        tell active tab
            execute javascript "function encryptDocument() {
                plainText = '" & docText & "';
                return plainText;
                } encryptDocument();"
            set skurp to the result
            display dialog skurp
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: You know, I never though about that, but that is the exact reason. Thanks! It seems there are some things in my real code that I need to change.

Comment: Do you know of a way to escape single quotes though?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include some applescript to escape single quotes. I didn't immediately find a builtin function that can do the same.